# Drivers for zebronics zeb-H61 motherboard with Ubuntu desktop

Tags: drivers

How to install drivers for zebronics zeb-H61 motherboard from Ubuntu desktop? Probably we can install it from Windows easily, but how to do so with Ubuntu.

Comment: You've provided no release details; and if a LTS release which kernel stack you're using. Motherboards are just branded boards on which chips are installed, where it's the chips installed that really matter, and you gave no details. On short-run boards (*manufactured*) the chips don't tend to change, but on popular boards (*manufactured longer term*) chips can change thus chips really matter. It's these chips that matter, and you've provided no specifics; the chips relate to kernel modules (commonly called *drivers*) which need release & kernel stack matter of which you gave no specifics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) Try running an Ubuntu live session from a bootable Ubuntu live USB. Motherboards are almost always plug and play in Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, for inconvenience short information. My PC runs with i5 5470 3.2-3.6ghz lga 1155 processor, Zebronics zeb-H61 lga 1155 motherboard, 2 Hynix ddr3 4gb ram sticks, 500gb hard disk, reo AMD radeon 7300HD 1GB ddr3 graphics card, 450 watt Psu. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which is pretty good but some of the functions are not working due to some driver issues. Like graphics and wifi and Bluetooth which are must for me. I just wanted to know how to install drivers for Ubuntu. Is there any driver pack solution as for windows or something source to get drivers.

Comment: Please ask a separate question regarding each problem you have. There are no "motherboard drivers" for Linux.